# How to export form as an image (not during runtime)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I'm using Visual Studio just to create GUIs for a project.  **There is no code, only the designs.**

I need to convert these forms into images that I can paste into the report.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks.

Edit: the only solution I have so far is to edit the project so that each window I want to export is the start up form, but I am going to have over 40 forms, so this will get tedious after awhile.

Comment: Odd requirement.  Why not just press the Print Screen key when you have the form opened in the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Class in your Projects, lets say Startup.vb, which looks something like this:

```
Friend Class Startup

    <STAThread()> _
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Application.Run(New Form1)
        Application.Run(New Form2)
        Application.Run(New Form3)
    End Sub

End Class
```

In the Project Properties the general Tab, *untick* **Enable application framework** and choose Startup as new start-object.

Obviously you'd need to adjust your startup class to open all forms you wish to open. When running the application just press **Alt+PrintScr** to copy an image of just the selected Window/Form to the clipboard. Paste that back into the paint application of your choice. Microsoft Paint will do.

Answer (score 0):

Using a screen capture program might be your best choice. Personally I recommend TechSmith SnagIt application. You can capture any selected region in the screen using this application.

Comment: Well, the problem is I need it to be exact, and also when in the design view, the handles for resizing the form overlap the form's edges.

Comment: @user1029167 you can just click on a control on the form to remove the form resize handles (these will move the resize handles to the control you clicked however)

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the form a select `Lock Controls` this will remove the resize handles you can then press `PrtScn` to take a copy.

Note: After applying `Lock Controls` it does still have a focus rectangle and lock symbol but these are outside the co-ordinates of the form so they could be cropped in MS Paint or similar?